# 502 HTTP Response Code in Facebook Debugger when trying to access image, I can access image fine using the URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-response-codes, facebook-debugger

I have an image that is served up in the og:image metatag so that it can be the image in a Facebook share post. However, when I use the debugger it gives me:

> Error while downloading http://www.example.com/images/image.png with HTTP response code: 502

I can go to the URL and receive the image fine with a status code of 200. Does anybody have any idea what could be the issue? I was sure it used to work fine on Facebook but maybe didn't try with this exact image. Facebook is also okay with other images in the same folder.

Comment: I know it's been some time but … did you find out what your problem was?

Comment: No sorry, never got a response or a solution wherever I posted this. It was a while ago and I can't exactly remember what I did to solve it sorry, I think I just hosted the image somewhere else and the debugger was fine with it being served from somewhere else. It was weird and frustrating to say the least!